# Como obtener el valor de un dropdownlist al momento de registrar con Asp.Net Framework MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

En mi controlador de registro de usuarios tengo lo siguiente

```
   [AllowAnonymous]
   public ActionResult Register()
   {    
      var categorias = db.Categoria.ToList().Where(x=>x.Estado);    
      var list = new SelectList(categorias, "Codigo", "Descripcion");

      ViewData["categorias"] = list;    
      ViewBag.Drop= new SelectList(categorias, "Codigo", "Descripcion");
      return View();
   }
```

Esto me llena correctamente un `DropDownList`  a la hora de cargar la vista. Sin embargo cuando intento realizar el registro, es decir cuando trato de guardar los datos en la base de datos me da el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código para guardar en la base de datos o el método `POST` es el que sigue :

```
// POST: /Account/Register
   [HttpPost]
   [AllowAnonymous]
   [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
   public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, HttpPostedFileBase upload)
   {
      ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser();
      byte[] foto;
      string categ = model.Categoria;

      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {         
         if (upload != null && upload.ContentLength > 0)
         {
            using (var reader = new System.IO.BinaryReader(upload.InputStream))
            {
               foto = reader.ReadBytes(upload.ContentLength);
            }

            user = new ApplicationUser
            {
               UserName = model.Email,
               Email = model.Email,
               Hometown = model.Hometown,
               Direccion = model.Direccion,
               NombreComercial = model.NombreComercial,
               Tipo = "Comercio",
               Estado = true,
               Foto = foto,
               Link = model.Link,
               Cedula = model.Cedula,
               Categoria= categ
            };
         }
         else
         {
            user = new ApplicationUser
            {
               UserName = model.Email,
               Email = model.Email,
               Hometown = model.Hometown,
               Direccion = model.Direccion,
               NombreComercial = model.NombreComercial,
               Tipo = "Comercio",
               Estado = true,
               Foto = model.Foto,
               Link = model.Link,
               Cedula = model.Cedula,
               Categoria = categ
            };
         }

         var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

         if (result.Succeeded)
         {
            await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);       
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
         }
         AddErrors(result);
      }     
      return View(model);
   }
```

Comment: Hola, indica en la pregunta el código de la Acción donde **guardas los datos en la base de datos*. Ya que es ahí donde te está dando el error..

Comment: @RafaelAcosta listo. Lo curioso es que el dato del dropdownlist llega bien a la variable categ  que declare. Pero cuando se llama el método UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password); ahi es donde se cae.

Comment: hola haz intentado hacer una clase view model? public class CategoriaViewModel
{
  [Display(Name = "Codigo Categoria")]
  public string Codigo { get; set; }
  
  public string Descripcion { get; set; }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema lo tienes cuando intentas crear el Modelo `UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password)` **sin éxito**.

Entonces tu Acción **Register [HttpPost]** te devuelve a la Vista `Register.cshtml` con el Modelo `RegisterViewModel`:

```
return View(model);
```

Una vez en la Vista, se intenta crear de nuevo el `DropDownListFor()` pero ya no existe el `ViewData["categorias"]` con las categorías. Así que deberías volver a crearlo antes de llamar a la Vista:

```
var categorias = db.Categoria.ToList().Where(x=>x.Estado);
var list = new SelectList(categorias, "Codigo", "Descripcion");
ViewData["categorias"] = list;
// Ahora si puedes llamar a la Vista.
return View(model);
```

Comment: Gracias, me salvaste la tanda de nuevo